# C Program to Print Prime Numbers From 1 to 100 (problem at inner and outer loop variable)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, variables

```c
// C Program to Print Prime Numbers From 1 to 100
#include
int main() {
  int i, num, count;

  // Checking for prime numbers
  for (num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
    count = 0;
    for (i = 2; i <= num/2; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        count++;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Checking and Printing Prime Numbers
    if (count == 0 && num != 1) {
      printf("%d \n", num);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand, if I put `0` at the start of the count variable (i.e., `int i, num, count=0;` like this) the code is not working. But if you put `count=0` inside the for loop it is working. Why is this happening?

Comment: The code you won't even build, it's not a [mre].

Comment: As for your problem, if you initialize `count` to zero at definition then you will count not only up to `100` but also all primes up to `1`, up to `2`, up to `3` and so on. All of those counts would be accumulated into `count`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Readability matters. Do yourself and everyone else a favor and apply some decent formatting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For more clarity you should provide the 2 versions of the code you are talking about. Describing changes in the code is always a bit ambiguous. Instead better show it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you wrote that code yourself.
Why did you add `count` variable to start with if you do not seem to know how it works?

> I don't understand, if I put 0 at the start of the count variable (i.e., int i, num, count=0; like this) the code is not working. But if you put count=0 inside the for loop it is working. Why is this happening?

That variable is used to detect if any value of `i` is found where `num` is a multiple of `i`. If that is the case (`count != 0` it is not a prime.
Of course you need to do this for each number `num` which means you must reset `count` for each iteration of the outer loop.

If you only do it once where you define the variable, it will never find any prime number any more after you saw the first none-prime number.

Working code:

```c
// C Program to Print Prime Numbers From 1 to 100
#include
int main(void) {
  int i, num, count;

  // Checking for prime numbers
  for (num = 2; num <= 100; num++) {
    count = 0;  // This is the indicator whether a number is prime
                // We must reset it here for each number we check.
    for (i = 2; i <= num/2; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        count++;
        break;
      }
    }

    // Checking and Printing Prime Numbers
    if (count == 0) {
      printf("%d \n", num);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Broken code:

```c
// C Program to Print Prime Numbers From 1 to 100
#include
int main(void) {
  int i, num, count = 0;  // This is only set to 0 once for all numbers we check.

  // Checking for prime numbers
  for (num = 2; num <= 100; num++) {
    for (i = 2; i <= num/2; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        count++;  // count will never become 0 again.
                  // We will not be able to detect any prime number after this.
        break;
      }
    }

    // Checking and Printing Prime Numbers
    if (count == 0) {
      printf("%d \n", num);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Not related to your problem but some detail to improve the code:

Why do you start with `num=1` if you later check `num != 1`?
Instead start at `num=2`.

Or print `2` before you start the loop. Then run the loop from `num=3` and increment `num+=2` to only check the odd numbers.

Comment: I think none of the answerers checks this code in the compiler. Please run this code in the compiler and answer briefly.

Comment: Why would one need to look what the compiler creates? If you do not put `count=0;` into the outer loop, the algorithm cannot work because the logic is broken.